# How I can place overflow menu below toolbar instead of overflow menu to overlaps the tool bar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

[image: intial view]


[image: on tapping share icon ,popup covers the toolbar content]


[image: on tapping see all option in popup, it shows properly below the toolbar]

I have added the shareActionProvider for the tool bar my problem is as soon as i tap on share icon the popup menu will cover the toolbar content but when i tap on **see all** option listed under the popup menu , the popup menu will perfectly settle below the tool bar.

My requirement is as soon as i tap on share icon my popup menu should be populated below the tool bar not after i select the **see all** option.

menu.xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_item_share"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:title="Share"
    android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_menu_share_mtrl_alpha"/>
```

Java code

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

    mShareActionProvider = new ShareActionProvider(getActivity()) {
        @Override
        public View onCreateActionView() {
            return null;
        }
    };

    MenuItemCompat.setActionProvider(item, mShareActionProvider);

    if (mShareActionProvider != null) {
        mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(createShareIntent());
    }
}
```

style.xml

```
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/colorPrimary</item>

    <!-- Required for pre-Lollipop. -->
    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">-4.0dip</item>

    <!-- Required for Lollipop. -->
    <item name="android:overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">-4.0dip</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 12):

According to the [Material Design specifications](http://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/structure.html#structure-app-bar) (see the Menus section):

> A menu is a temporary sheet of paper that always overlaps the app bar, rather than behaving as an extension of the app bar.

[image: Menu overlap app bar]

So what you are seeing is the correct Material design for menus.

---

To change it in your main style use  `<item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>`, where

```
<style name="OverflowMenu" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
  <!-- Required for pre-Lollipop. -->
   <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
   <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">-4.0dip</item>
  <!-- Required for Lollipop. -->
   <item name="android:overlapAnchor">false</item>
   <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">4.0dip</item>
</style>
```

For Lollipop style must be in `values-v21`.