# Menu icon doesn't show up

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-menu, android-icons

I've read thousands of questions like this and seams even following the most basics tutorials I can't get it to work.

I've a toolbar with a menu, but the items icon doens't show up, neither at preview nor runtime:
[image]

The icons are drawable from svg and all of them show fine when I try to place at `buttons` or `imageviews`

my menu is:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".activities.MenuAdsAppCompatActivity">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_notification1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_more"
        android:title="action_notification">

        <item android:id="@+id/action_share_us"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
            android:title="@string/share_us" />
        <item android:id="@+id/action_rate_us"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
            android:title="@string/rate" />
        <item android:id="@+id/action_about"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"
            android:title="@string/about" />
    </item>

</menu>
```

Another thing is at runtime the menu is covering the toolbar and i would like it to behave like the design preview where the menu is starting from the bottom of toolbar

===================UPDATE=============================

relevant activity methods:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_toolbar, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void setContentView(@LayoutRes int layoutResID) {
        super.setContentView(layoutResID);
        ViewGroup v = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) this.findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);
        this.helpView = (WebView) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.html_dialog, null);
        v.addView(toolbar, 0);

        try {
            ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams layout = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
            layout.setMargins(-v.getPaddingLeft(), -v.getPaddingTop(), -v.getPaddingRight(), v.getPaddingTop()+5);
            toolbar.setLayoutParams(layout);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    }
```

================================ UPDATE 2 ==============

With the suggestion of @Dhiraj the icons now are OK... but I still would like to make the menu NOT cover the toolbar

[image]

Comment: Your question is incomplete. Add the Activity code . and style .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap your items inside `<menu>`and add `app:showAsAction="always"` to your parent item.

Updated menu :

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".activities.MenuAdsAppCompatActivity">

   <item android:id="@+id/action_notification1"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_more"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="action_notification">
        <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/action_share_us"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_share"
            android:title="@string/share_us" />
        <item android:id="@+id/action_rate_us"
            android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_info_details"
            android:title="@string/rate" />
        <item android:id="@+id/action_about"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"
            android:title="@string/about" />
        </menu>
    </item>

</menu>
```

---

And to show menu below toolbar you need to provide `actionOverflowMenuStyle` for your style.
For this please see : https://stackoverflow.com/a/34288434/3552066

Comment: BTW, do you know a simple way to change menu background color? some style attribute i can set? all answers I are more complicatd